# How to call NetDocuments SOAP API by java?

Tags: java, axis

I can call NetDocuments SOAP API by C# as following:

```
// Authenticate to the NetDocuments directory service
ndDir.Directory ndDirectory = new ndDir.Directory();
ndDirectory.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer(); // enable cookie handling
ndDirectory.Login( username, password );

// Connect to the NetDocuments storage service
ndStor.storage ndStorage = new ndStor.storage();
ndStorage.CookieContainer = ndDirectory.CookieContainer;        // share cookies with the directory service
XmlNode searchRes = ndStorage.Search( criteria, attrList );
```

However, when I call NetDocuments SOAP API by java with Axis 1.4, I receive error: "No authentication session.  The authentication session has timed out or was not established prior to this call."

```
DirectorySoapStub stubDir = new DirectorySoapStub(new URL("https://vault.netvoyage.com/ndApi/directory.asmx"), new DirectoryLocator());
StorageSoapStub stubSto = new StorageSoapStub(new URL("https://vault.netvoyage.com/ndApi/storage.asmx"), new StorageLocator());
stubSto.setMaintainSession(true);
stubDir.login(username, password);

javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders mhds = stubDir._getCall().getMessageContext().getCurrentMessage().getMimeHeaders();
java.util.Iterator iterator = mhds.getAllHeaders();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader mhd = (javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader)iterator.next();
    if ("set-cookie".indexOf(mhd.getName()) >= 0) {
        stubSto._setProperty(mhd.getName(), mhd.getValue());
    }
}

stubSto.search(criteria, attrList);
```

Is there similar thing of CookieContainer in Java? How can I call NetDocuments SOAP API by java with Axis 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question was posted a while ago, but I've been able to get this working in the past by using the JAX-RPC plugin that comes with NetBeans.  The version of NetBeans I used was v6.8 (I think that the JAX-RPC plugin is not included in newer versions of NetBeans as JAX-RPC isn't widely used anymore). I remember struggling to get anything working when I tried to use Axis, though that was more than likely due to me not being familiar enough with it.

I can't remember all the steps necessary, but you can point the JAX-RPC plugin at the WSDL for NetDocuments and all the classes needed for calling the API are then set up for you.

To handle authentication correctly, it was necessary to set the SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY on the DirectorySoap_Stub and StorageSoap_Stub classes to true - this instructs them to maintain a session once you have logged in.  See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0177/fxybb/index.html for info on SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY

Additionally, when you login via the DirectorySoap object, if you then want to use the methods of StorageSoap you need to let the StorageSoap object know the cookie that you are using in the DirectorySoap session.

To do this I implemented a javax.xml.rpc.handler.Handler that stores the CookieJar from the DirectorySoap session (property "com.sun.xml.rpc.client.http.CookieJar" on the request MessageContext) and sets that CookieJar on the same property of requests of the StorageSoap session.

Hopefully that's useful to anyone with similar SOAP issues...

Cheers